# Preview mode not showing any In device preview in design tab in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I JUST UPDATED MY ANDROID STUDIO AND FACING THIS PROBLEM:
this is what i am getting at design tab no device at all in preview can't acess API levels
enter image description here[image]
the theme selection is just showing this , no description in right hand side

[image]

the text section of activity_main contains:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.akash.myapplicationddd.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my gradle(project):

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }  
}
```

task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir`enter code here`
   }

Comment: sry i don't can't figure out from where the last line came from !

Comment: @Akash Kabir plz restart your android studio and sync your project with gradle

Comment: getting the error gradle sync is failed try again

Comment: the thing is ..with newly created applications i am getting the preview mode  but with the already created projects there is no preview

Comment: @AkashKabir plz check my answer

Comment: my android studio version is 2.2.0

Comment: @AkashKabir Have you tried to restart your android studio ? Which version you have updated ?

Answer (score 0):

please change your gradle file

```
dependencies {
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'

// NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
// in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

change to your updated studio version